pine script : lowest and pivot detection
I want to retrieve the high value and the index of the pivot which is located just after the lowest or the highest.
on my graph I have the labels of the pivots but I cannot recover the high values ​​of the pivot and its index.
//pivot
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

//lowest et highest
lowest(x, i, o) =>
    var float min_0 = na
    var int min_idx = na
    if i > 1
        for a=o to o+i-1
            if x[a] < min_0 or na(min_0)
                min_0 := x[a]
                min_idx := a
    [min_0, min_idx]

highest(x, i, o) =>
    var float v = na
    var int idx = na
    if i > 1
        for a=o to o+i-1
            if x[a] > v or na(v)
                v := x[a]
                idx := a
//First pivot after lowest et highest in variable  => don't work
if not na(max_idx) and not na(pl) and pl > max_idx
    firstPivotLowValue := low[pl]
    firstPivotLowIndex := int(pl)  // Conversion explicite en `int`

if not na(min_idx) and not na(ph) and ph > min_idx
    firstPivotHighValue := high[ph]
    firstPivotHighIndex := int(ph)

recover the values ​​of the first pivot after lowest and highest.

How do you create the labels?
